# Boost Asio HTTP server won't display .xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, boost, boost-asio

I have HTTP Server 3 from
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html
running on localhost.
It opens html files fine, but when try to open xml file it displays it like a txt file (without little triangles for expanding separate tags and not color coded). xslt not working as well.

when I try to open xml directly (not using localhost:port) it works fine.

anyone knows what's the problem?
thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASIO. It's related to the browser and how it responds to content-type headers. You **may** add a content-type header

Comment: @sehe but I tried web server (php.net) on localhost and it works fine.

Comment: So, it responds with different headers. No contradiction. This is what web servers do; usually they have fixed mime-type mappings when serving static resources.

Comment: @sehe Sorry but i cant understand. why boost asio cant respond with different header?

Comment: Boost Asio can do anything. It's a networking library. What you send is your responsibility. Note I didn't say it couldn't be done.

Comment: `Boost.Asio` deals with lower-level protocols: TCP, UDP etc. If you wish to build an HTTP server, you can either construct it on top of Asio (just like it's done in the example you mention), or use a library that has higher-level interface, like [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) (which is built on top of Asio).

Comment: @IgorR. yes, I am using http server from the example. html pages are working.

Comment: But this is just an example. It doesn't promise to be perfect.

Comment: @IgorR. Are you saying that boost example is with errors? i tried several more web servers, they all display xml files.

Comment: It's not a bug, just a lack of feature. Add the appropriate mime type to the returned http headers, and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In **`mime_types.cpp`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server3/mime_types.cpp) add

```
{ "xml", "text/xml" },
```

So you get

```
struct mapping
{
    const char* extension;
    const char* mime_type;
} mappings[] =
{
    { "gif", "image/gif" },
    { "htm", "text/html" },
    { "html", "text/html" },
    { "jpg", "image/jpeg" },
    { "png", "image/png" },
    { "xml", "text/xml" },
    { 0, 0 } // Marks end of list.
};
```

`"application/xml"` should work just as well. Proof of working on my linux box:

[image]